# Evaluating the gradient of pressure at the boundary of container

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In the hydrostatic case with no viscosity, we can write the gradient of the pressure inside a container of water within the gravitational field as
$$ \nabla P = g \rho$$

Moving close to a wall vertical wall, We encounter a normal force which should reduce our pressure, however, due to the isotropic nature of pressure, the pressure downwards must be the same as total pressure to the wall and hence the normal shouldn't affect the gradient.

What exactly is the intuition behind the forces at the boundary not affecting the pressure at all even though the fluid is clearly being 'pushed'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think the normal force should reduce the pressure.  The normal force on the container is a *reaction* force.  The normal force on the ground when you step on it doesn't cause you to not weigh anything, it just prevents your weight from continuing to accelerate you downwards.  It's similar with pressure.  The force that the walls are feeling does not mean that it takes away from the pressure in the fluid, it is just the force that the walls of the container apply in response when pushed against by pressure.

You ask about:

> "the forces at the boundary not affecting the pressure at all"

But that is not correct.  The forces of the boundary are *necessary* for this pressure gradient to develop, so they have a very significant effect.

Without a solid boundary of the container to "push" at the fluid (or something else to keep it pushed together, like gravity on a larger scale), the force of the fluid pushing against itself would cause it to spread apart.  It would not be able to develop a pressure gradient because the water above pushing down on the water below would just cause the water below to push away due to the force of the water above, with nothing to stop it from moving away.

The normal force of the container is a *requirement* to contain the water pressure in the container.  Without that normal force pushing back, static pressure would not be able to develop.  Instead, the water would just spread out into as thin of a surface as it can, so that it is essentially all at rest at atmospheric pressure.  Even the normal force of the atmosphere helps keep the water contained, but that's more because that without the atmospheric pressure, the water would evaporate to fill the vacuum as much as possible.

Comment: Great answer, could you also explain how exactly the static pressure develops due to existence of normal force? (Molecular picture)

Comment: @Buraian I can't really give a good molecular picture here, no.  I'm pretty sure there are already some answers on this site about that, but pressure is more of a macroscopic property anyways.  There is a question that explains static pressure in terms of microscopic properties, but TBH I don't think it would make this answer any clearer, and probably more confusing if anything.